# How can i make Round shape menu in iPhone?

Tags: ios4, uibutton

[image]

Hi I want to make such kind of Menu in my iPhone Application.Please suggest me how can i implement this kind of menu in my iPhone Application.(circular menu, that gets highlited when touched)

Comment: this is also good example. http://www.tapsandswipes.com/frameworks/touchpie/

Answer (score 0):

openGLES is one option. or [this post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html). there are many options here it depends what you are most comfortable with.

Edit: [This too may help](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton)